# How to save the google login as an app user?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

So I have some code that authenticates the user to my app using google which works out fine. What I want to do is then save that user info to the firebase and then have that user be able add data specifically under their account that will then reload the next time they log in. What's the best way to do that? I'm getting very lost.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('life-of-a-story')
    .controller('UserController', function($scope, $firebaseAuth) {
      var ref = new Firebase('https://life-of-a-story.firebaseio.com/');
      // create an instance of the authentication service
      var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
      // login with Google
      this.login = function() {
        auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("google").then(function(authData) {
          console.log(authData);
          console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
          var user = {
            'name': authData.google.displayName,
            'image': authData.google.profileImageURL,
            'uid': authData.uid
          }
          console.log(user);
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Authentication failed:", error);
        });
      };
    });
})();
```

Comment: Most Firebase Authentication devs store each user's data under a `/users` node. Is that what you're looking for? If so: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing

Comment: omg that's exactly what I was looking for thank you haha, can you put that as answer so I can pick it?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure whether it can be an answer, since it's essentially just a link. On the other hand: you're the second one within a week to ask this, so clearly this is something we can improve in our docs. I'll write a slightly more elaborate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*AngularFire is a (relatively) thin UI binding library on top of Firebase's regular JavaScript SDK. So when something is not explicitly documented in the AngularFire documentation, you can sometimes find the answer in the [documentation for the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/).*

Most Firebase Authentication developers store each user's data under a `/users` node. If that is what you're trying to do, you can read how to accomplish it in the section called [Storing user data in the Firebase documentation for JavaScript](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing).

The relevant code from there:

```
// we would probably save a profile when we register new users on our site
// we could also read the profile to see if it's null
// here we will just simulate this with an isNewUser boolean
var isNewUser = true;
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData && isNewUser) {
    // save the user's profile into the database so we can list users,
    // use them in Security and Firebase Rules, and show profiles
    ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set({
      provider: authData.provider,
      name: getName(authData)
    });
  }
});
// find a suitable name based on the meta info given by each provider
function getName(authData) {
  switch(authData.provider) {
     case 'password':
       return authData.password.email.replace(/@.*/, '');
     case 'twitter':
       return authData.twitter.displayName;
     case 'facebook':
       return authData.facebook.displayName;
  }
}
```